# Passing an array to function and use it in WHERE IN clause

Tags: arrays, oracle, plsql

I want to use array(which is passed to function) under `Where in` clause

**Here is what i tried**

First created the array type

```
 create or replace type p_emp_arr as table of number
```

Function is

```
 create or replace
    FUNCTION getEmployee_func ( empId_arr IN p_emp_arr)
    RETURN number IS
       total number(2) := 0;

      BEGIN 

  IF(empId_arr is null)   
   THEN
    empIdClause := '';
   ELSE
      empIdClause := 'AND Employee.empId in (select column_value from table('||empId_arr||'))'; 
  END IF;

        ....
        RETURN total;
     END;
```

But gives error

```
 Error(17,23): PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to '||'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because `CONCAT (||)` operator accepts only **scalar** variables (string/number), you cannot pass an array to it.

You need to execute this as a dynamic PL/SQL block.

In case you want to bind the array dynamically, try something like this.
Bind the variables using `IN` and `OUT` keywords appropriately.

In your *Anonymous* block string, prefix the to-be-bind variables with `colon (:)`

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '
  BEGIN
       SELECT
         COLUM1,COLUMN2..
       INTO
         :VAR1, :VAR2..
       FROM .... WHERE...
       AND Employee.empId in (select column_value from table(:empId_arr));
  END;
  '
  USING OUT VAR1, OUT VAR2... IN empId_arr;
```

It can also be Simply,

```
OPEN EMP_CURSOR FOR
  'SELECT * FROM Employee 
      where empId in SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE(:empId_arr)'
   USING empId_arr ;
```

If you take the output as a cursor;

AS [Wernfried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27666198/passing-an-array-to-function-and-use-it-in-where-in-clause/27666635?noredirect=1#comment43751137_27666635) mentioned.. Using `MEMBER OF` operator.

```
OPEN EMP_CURSOR FOR
  'SELECT * FROM Employee 
      where empId member of :empId_arr'
   USING empId_arr ;
```

Comment: Thanks Maheswaran. One quick thing if empId_arr  is null i want to assign default value as 0. I tried empId_arr :=p_emp_arr(0); but it gives error 
Error(17,6): PLS-00363: expression 'empId_arr' cannot be used as an assignment target

Comment: Can the default be assigned to the array instead

Comment: If emp_arr is null then Emp_arr.extend; emp_arr(1):=0 end if;

Comment: but it still says Error(17,5): PLS-00363: expression 'emp_ARR' cannot be used as an assignment target

Comment: Sorry sorry, the variable is of IN type. Which means READONLY, changing it to IN OUT will work. But if you don't want to, then you may need to create a local copy.

Comment: even changing it to IN out gives error but at run time now PLS-00363: expression '<expression>' cannot be used as an assignment target

Comment: Lets create a duplicate variable of it locally.

Comment: but duplicate variable has to have different name. Right ?

Comment: Yes, always use tht variable for binding

Comment: It goes even shorter: ' where empId member of :empId_arr'
   USING empId_arr ;

Comment: @Wernfried Great.. I never knew ,it do exist.!!